# Shiro - How to represent an anonymous/guest user with permissions?

Tags: shiro

Our company is providing a service where a user can register and upload files. After login, a user can see access his uploaded files, upload more files, analyze them etc.

This works fine but we would also like to provide something like an anonymous/guest login, where users still can upload files but which are not accessible any more as soon as the session expires (after about 8 hours).

How would I implement something like that with Shiro? I know Shiro has the notion of an anonymous user but it seems I am not able to add permissions to him.

Comment: Can't you just create a real user for this (with user/pass guest/guest) and add the correct permissions to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a real user for this (with user/pass guest/guest) and add the correct permissions to it.

Comment: when resource is requested via HTTP programmatically, it means that client should implement authentication, which makes client code much verbose.